# Decommissioning Domain Controller in South America

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory

I am in the US, I have a replicate domain controller in Colombia that connects to here via a site-to-site vpn connection for replication.  I have only 1 user that uses that DC to authenticate.  It is also the DNS server.  It is on a different subnet as well.

I have remote access to it.  What I need to do is log in remotely and decommission it so they can send it back to me.  However I need to make sure they will be able to log in to their computer since the DC they use to authenticate won't be there.  I just want him connecting to VPN to access his usual resources (mostly exchange).

I know how to log in and decommission it, but how will I tell the single users laptop there to no longer authenticate on that DC and to just use a VPN connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a VPN connection created on that computer, rather than your router. In this case when the user comes to login they will not have a connection to a domain controller.  This may not be a big problem initially as they will be able to login with a cached login, start a Vpn connection and connect to the domain services. However you may want to evaluate whether there is any benefit to leaving it on the domain, Or just removing it and using outlook anywhere to access exchange and providing them with file access where required via the VPN.

Comment: The site-to-site connection is done via a router.  I want to remove the router though and allow the client to use vpn instead after decommissioning the domain controller.  Will the client still use cached login instead once the dc is gone on that site?

Comment: Also: would it be best to go ahead and tell this client computer to not use this domain controller and require a VPN connection ot the main office?  How would I go about doing that?